# QGIS 3.22.16. Layouts Atlas option: Adding all the data in the last map of the Atlas

Tags: qgis, layouts, linestring, scale, atlas

I created an Atlas to get different location maps of one data. Is it possible to add a map at the end of the atlas that shows the data in the entire county?[image]

Comment: You use a layer for the different extend of your atlas, so just add a polygon of the entire extend! No?

Comment: You can use Report instead of Atlas

Answer (score 2):

You can add a second page to your atlas and then set the "Exclude from exports" at the page properties of the second page with a data defined override to only export it once with the last atlas feature:

`@atlas_featurenumber < @atlas_totalfeatures - 1`

[image]